# Argument 'ListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm new to Karma and Jasmine, and wanted to get some assistance trying to use grunt test on controllers. The error I get when I run the test is (shortened):

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern     "/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.1)]: Connected on socket 34BLydt6tI-UpBXZQBCZ
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.1) Controllers ListCtrl should have list of recipes FAILED
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/ng/areq?p0=ListCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at /Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1360:11)
    at assertArgFn (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1370:3)
    at /Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6755:9
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/test/spec/controllers/controllers.js:21:14)
    at Object.invoke (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3697:17)
    at workFn (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2102:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2087:25)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/test/spec/controllers/controllers.js:17:16)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/test/spec/controllers/controllers.js:13:3)
    at /Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/test/spec/controllers/controllers.js:1:1
Expected undefined to equal [ 1, 2, 3 ].
Error: Expected undefined to equal [ 1, 2, 3 ].
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/test/spec/controllers/controllers.js:28:30)
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.1) Controllers EditController should save the recipe FAILED
```

...

Controllers.js test:

```
            describe('Controllers', function() {
              var $scope, ctrl;
              //you need to indicate your module in a test
              beforeEach(module('chapter4App',
                  ['directives', 'services']));
              beforeEach(function() {
                this.addMatchers({
                  toEqualData: function(expected) {
                    return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
                  }
                });
              });

              describe('ListCtrl', function() {
                var mockBackend, recipe;
                // The _$httpBackend_ is the same as $httpBackend. Only written this way to
                // differentiate between injected variables and local variables
                beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_, Recipe) {
                  recipe = Recipe;
                  mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
                  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                  ctrl = $controller('ListCtrl', {
                    $scope: $scope,
                    recipes: [1, 2, 3]
                  });
                }));

                it('should have list of recipes', function() {
                  expect($scope.recipes).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
                });
              });
```

Please look at https://github.com/doronkatz/angularjs-book/tree/master/chapter4 which has the code, including test script for the controller, and controller.

Comment: I really think you should try and reduce the code dump in your question.

Comment: OK Stewie, yeah i was just about to do that when you commented :) thanks

Comment: Well, replacing the actual code with a reference link to an external resource is also not a good SO practice. What I was saying is, you should iteratively remove parts of your code until you're left with bare minimum that still produces the same error. And than you should post only that much code.

Comment: Yeah but as I'm new I also don't know whats vital to show what's not vital to show. I wasnt sure if i need to show more than just the test controller, any config files etc...

Answer (score 0):

4th line:

WARN [watcher]: Pattern     "/Users/doronkatz/Development/Angular/Chapter4/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.

Sooo, maybe You dont load all required files?

Comment: I've created all of these using scaffolding via yo angular etc... It should take care of it all right? I've got a feeling it is in the controller.js file/files, somewhere....

Comment: Open debug in chrome and see if everything is loaded into karma. Thats my first and probably last guess ;)

Comment: I think that issues is that You use 1.2.6 angular and original source code is for 1.0.8. There were some breaking changes between versions.

Comment: Ah really, that much breaking... :/ shouldn't be that signficant considering its a .x version difference. The errors aren't very clear either